# DocuSign "View Documents" button does not reflect branding - company name

Tags: docusignapi, resource-files

We are a third party service provider that relies on the branding feature of DocuSign to appear that all documents come from our clients.  For the most part, this works very well.  The only issue we are struggling with is the loss of branding when a signer clicks on the 'view documents' button in an email.  The landing page picks up the name of our firm instead of our client's company name.

For example, the emails we send look like:

Sender = John Smith at "ABC Company" (our client)

However when the sender clicks the "View Documents" button, the landing page request for signature dialog box reads

Sender = John Smith at "XYZ Company" (our company's name)

DocuSign has directed us to the Master Resource Files to implement this correction.  We have downloaded the files, but it is unclear where we need edit to affect this change.  Before we resort to the "trial and error" method, we thought someone here may be able to advise us.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to have that 'landing page' display the Sender's company name instead of the Account's company name. However, you could remove the 'sender' information from that 'landing page' altogether, by setting the value of **DocuSign_HideIntroductionSender** to **true** in the **DocuSign_SignResources.xml** file.

[image: DS setting]

Comment: Hiding the Introduction Header is exactly what we have done and it works well.  We have also hidden the Consumer Disclosure since it too picks up the [[SenderAccount]] field data.  We would prefer to be able to plug in our client's branding, but for now at least hiding the information is better than putting out misleading information.  Thanks for your answer.